# proper Roles and permission to use Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I am using [`Azure Data Studio`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15). Which roles should I add to the user? There is an error when I use the `Start New Profiler session`:

```
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Azure Data Studio SQL Profiler you may need to have Control permission over the database, The database owner has Control permission.

Comment: It worked but is it possible to give less permission?

Comment: No. It is not possible because Azure Data Studio SQL Profiler uses extended events and to run extended events you need Control permission.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by granting `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission. This is a development server so it's not an issue for me if the user has more permission than it needs.

```sql
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [Username]
```

Answer (score -1):

To be able to execute a stored procedure for example you could do this:

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON [SCHEMA].[TABLE] to [USER]
```

Comment: This answer does not relate to the question.